# New Column relative to date in R

Tags: r

the title is terrible but let me try to explain what I want (Example I made in Excel)

```
Div Date       FTHG FTA R   Weight  Home    Away
I1  30.08.2014  0   1   A   0,72    0,00    0,72
I1  30.08.2014  2   0   H   0,72    1,45    0,00
I1  14.09.2014  4   5   A   0,73    2,91    3,64
I1  14.09.2014  2   0   H   0,73    1,45    0,00
I1  15.09.2014  2   1   H   0,73    1,45    0,73
I1  20.09.2014  2   2   D   0,73    1,46    1,46
I1  20.09.2014  0   1   A   0,73    0,00    0,73
I1  21.09.2014  0   1   A   0,73    0,00    0,73
I1  21.09.2014  2   3   A   0,73    1,46    2,20
I1  21.09.2014  1   0   H   0,73    0,73    0,00
I1  21.09.2014  1   1   D   0,73    0,73    0,73
I1  21.09.2014  2   0   H   0,73    1,46    0,00
```

I need 3 new columns:

**Weight**: The closer the date gets to today, the closer the "Weight" Column should go to 1.

**Home**: Weight * FTHG

**Away**: Weight * FTA

How can I do this in R?
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of function would like to use to calculate the weights? At what point does the weight become zero, do the weights increase linearly or logarithmically? Please expand your question.

Comment: exponential smoothing, sigma 0,065

Answer (score 1):

Convert your date string into a Date object and subtract from today to find the time difference.  Create an exponential based on this time difference and a time-constant.  Use this to construct your weights, and then multiply by the appropriate columns.

```
cols <- c('Div', 'Date', 'FTHG', 'FTA', 'R')
d <- rbind(
    c('I1','30.08.2014','0','1','A'),
    c('I1','30.08.2014','2','0','H'),
    c('I1','14.09.2014','4','5','A'),
    c('I1','14.09.2014','2','0','H'),
    c('I1','15.09.2014','2','1','H'),
    c('I1','20.09.2014','2','2','D'),
    c('I1','20.09.2014','0','1','A'),
    c('I1','21.09.2014','0','1','A'),
    c('I1','21.09.2014','2','3','A'),
    c('I1','21.09.2014','1','0','H'),
    c('I1','21.09.2014','1','1','D'),
    c('I1','21.09.2014','2','0','H')
)

df <- data.frame(d)
colnames(df) <- cols

# Adjust this
time_constant <- 5.79

df$Weight <- exp( -( (as.numeric(Sys.Date() - as.Date(df$Date,"%d.%m.%Y"))) / 365 )
                  / time_constant )

df$Home <- df$Weight * as.numeric( as.vector( df$FTHG ))
df$Away <- df$Weight * as.numeric( as.vector( df$FTA  ))

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    Div       Date FTHG FTA R    Weight      Home      Away
 1   I1 30.08.2014    0   1 A 0.7248692 0.0000000 0.7248692
 2   I1 30.08.2014    2   0 H 0.7248692 1.4497384 0.0000000
 3   I1 14.09.2014    4   5 A 0.7300325 2.9201298 3.6501623
 4   I1 14.09.2014    2   0 H 0.7300325 1.4600649 0.0000000
 5   I1 15.09.2014    2   1 H 0.7303780 1.4607559 0.7303780
 6   I1 20.09.2014    2   2 D 0.7321080 1.4642161 1.4642161
 7   I1 20.09.2014    0   1 A 0.7321080 0.0000000 0.7321080
 8   I1 21.09.2014    0   1 A 0.7324545 0.0000000 0.7324545
 9   I1 21.09.2014    2   3 A 0.7324545 1.4649091 2.1973636
 10  I1 21.09.2014    1   0 H 0.7324545 0.7324545 0.0000000
 11  I1 21.09.2014    1   1 D 0.7324545 0.7324545 0.7324545
 12  I1 21.09.2014    2   0 H 0.7324545 1.4649091 0.0000000
```